# How To include Visual Studio 2010 and WinDDK 7.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kernel, wdk

I try to create Kernel driver using Windows 7 + Visual studio 2010 + WDK 7.0. Next i install all tools, i don't find WDK in Visual Studio when I start create project. I try to include the path of WDK in VC++ directure but I get "VC++ Directories editing in Tools>Options has been deprecated".

There is same one can tell me how to include WDK in VS2010.
Thx

Comment: You now use the View | Property Manager window to edit global VS directories.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498441/global-vc-directories-for-visual-studio-2010-or-later/17498563#17498563).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. VS2010 isn't suitable for driver building. The best you can do is to use it as IDE and invoke the external WDK script for compilation. You need to move to VS2012+ and WDK 8+ to have an integrated driver development environment.

Comment: I need to create driver for windows server 2003. So i should use WDK 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual studio 2008 to create kernel driver. And to build project i installed a virtual machine running windows 7 and on it I installed VisualDDK. But when i start debugging, my virtual machine block. Relay i don't understood why.

There is same one can help me.