# Global VC++ Directories for Visual Studio 2010 or later

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

How can I change the **global** Visual C++ directories in Visual Studio 2010 or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Toolset.props` files for Visual Studio 2013 can be found in:

```
%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v120
%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v120_xp
%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v120
%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v120_xp
```

The files for other versions of Visual Studio should be in similar locations.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx), Open View|Project Manager and edit the item in the tree called Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user (or Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user for 64-bit projects).

Comment: Isn't that per-user, not global on the entire machine?

Comment: Yes, it's per-user, but global for all projects.

Comment: lol if it's per-user then it's not global... that's like saying `My Documents` is a "global" folder.

Comment: Indeed. In fact, if it's only per-machine it's not really global either. But generally we accept that "global" means "global within a given scope". Surely when you're writing code you don't complain that global variables are actually limited to a single program?